# Evaluate the integral via integration by parts strategy

Tags: integration

$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} x\cos(\pi x) dx $

$$
\begin{align}
u &= x & dv &= \cos(\pi x) dx \\
du &= dx & v &= \frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi x) \textrm{ via substitution rule} \\
\end{align}
$$

That leaves me with:

$$= \frac{x}{\pi} \sin(\pi x) -  \int_{} \frac{1}{\pi} \sin(\pi x)dx \\
= \frac{x}{\pi} \sin(\pi x) + \frac{1}{\pi}\cos(\pi x) \textrm{ substitution rule again} \\ = \frac{1}{\pi}(x\sin(\pi x) + \cos(\pi x)$$

Then I evaluate the upper and lower bounds of the original integral:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2} + \cos\frac{\pi}{2} \bigg) - \frac{1}{\pi} \bigg( 0\sin(\pi 0) + \cos(\pi 0) \bigg) \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi}(1 + 0) - \frac{1}{\pi} (1+0)$$

I know this is wrong because the answer key is $\frac{\pi - 2}{2\pi^2}$. This is starting to get very frustrating for me because the concept of doing integration by parts is straight forward, but choosing the right $u/dv$ is EVERYTHING and between that and remembering all the small integration techniques for trig and logs and everything else, it is overwhelming for me and I don't feel like I am improving at this at all.

What areas should I focus on to improve my integration by parts skills so that I can get through the problems faster and at least, if I make a mistake, that I am able to actually spot said mistake in my work without having to redo it 3-4 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you solved the integral for $\sin(\pi x)$ by substitution, you should get an additional factor of $1/\pi$. Therefore, you have $1/\pi$ from the integration by parts and $1/\pi$ from integrating the sine function. The answer is  $$\frac{1}{\pi}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac 1\pi\cos\frac{\pi}{2} \bigg) - \frac{1}{\pi} \bigg( 0\sin(\pi 0) + \frac 1\pi\cos(\pi 0) \bigg) \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi}(1 + 0) - \frac{1}{\pi^2} (1+0)=\frac{\pi-2}{2\pi^2}$$